# Where do I keep .swf files in Java Web application?

Tags: java

like presently I have 10 games and I placed those in my WEB-CONTENT folder.
In future if i have 100+ number of games then do I need to place all those in that folder only..??? Is this the right thing I am doing?

Thanks

Comment: create subfolder(s) and place them. You could do some thing like create categories for your games and placing them like that as in `web-content/games/action`, `web-content/games/mystery`, `web-content/games/puzzle` etc

Comment: Please tell me how this is relevant to programming.. it looks like a question of internal organisation to me.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is the right way to do it. Place all the resources of your application ( including .swf files ) in the WebContent folder.

As a best practice is to create a hierarchical structure of folders inside the WebContent. ( eq: type of games, date, and so on )

Also there is an alternative, to investigate if there is a need to keep those games in other servers. And the reason is that we will have massive download on your main application. In order to simulate that you can have multiple java applications for your main app and for the replicated machines that only keep the specific games. ( this is a use case for the new games, or high wanted resources )